# PayPalPaymentViewController User Interaction Not Enabled

Tags: ios, mobile, paypal, sdk, cocoapods

I have a PayPalPaymentViewController using the PayPal-iOS-SDK Cocoapod and a bridging header. Here is my code for generating the payment VC. It is being instantiated and presented, but none of the buttons work (except cancel). I can't Login or Checkout With CC.

Xcode 8.3.3

iOS 10.3.2

```
func showPayPalViewController() {
    // PayPal Payment Configurations
    let ppConfig = PayPalConfiguration()
        ppConfig.acceptCreditCards = true
        ppConfig.merchantName = "Temp Merch Name"
        ppConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = .none
        ppConfig.sandboxUserPassword = "Boatboat1"

    // Item To Be Paid For
    let ppPayment = PayPalPayment(amount: 2000.00, currencyCode: "USD", shortDescription: "Temp Service Name", intent: .sale)
        ppPayment.paymentDetails = PayPalPaymentDetails(subtotal: 2000.00, withShipping: 0.0, withTax: 0.0)

    // Instanciate Payment VC
    let ppViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: ppPayment, configuration: ppConfig, delegate: self)
    present(ppViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: PayPalPaymentViewController Image]

So the question I have is why can't I click "Log in" or "Pay with Card"

Comment: did you put put proper information in input boxes with validation?

Comment: @iOSDev I don't understand your question. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare buttons actions for each functioning button. May be try using IBAction and declare values for buttons. That would be a best approach.!

Comment: The view controller is not storyboarded. It is created using the PayPal Mobile SDK and therefore I have no control over the buttons on said controller. Do you have an example?

Comment: Specifically, once this VC is added to the stack, the buttons don't work. I feel like I am doing something wrong. I need someone with PayPal SDK experience: `let payPalViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)!`

Comment: okay. If you are not using storyboard, You should have declared your buttons using UIButton, and so on defining the button.!!

Comment: This view controller is built in to the PayPal SDK. I shouldn't have to do any of that.